# divs not floating as expected

Tags: html, css

I have a containing div with 3 boxes inside of it. I'm trying to get them to display on the same line as each other.

I've used floats to try achieve this but they appear messed up.

I know this is a common problem and have looked through here to find what I was looking for but none of the solutions seemed to work as expected.

Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DPMC87/k94xxsof/1/)

```
<div class="aboutcol1">

  <div class="aboutbox1">
    <div id="aboutbox-image1">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="aboutbox2">
    <div id="aboutbox-image2">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="aboutbox3">
    <div id="aboutbox-image3">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: in your fiddle the `.aboutbox2` is not floating, so its just a regular display block div

Comment: suggestion: you have some repeating css and can clean it up by making a class that the images share. Check out this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0L141puq/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to put float rule to div with class `aboutbox2`

Try this fiddle and see if only the float was the issue.
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k94xxsof/2/)

Comment: So simple thank you. Think I was staring at it for too long :( Will accept when it let's me!

Comment: as advice: do not use ids. In you case you can do the job with child selector ` > `. You see how you can miss something when styles get messy with lots of ids

Comment: Worked like a charm thank you. I'll keep that in mind cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't put float left for .aboutbox2 class

updated css

```
.aboutboxes1 {
  min-width:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  width: 100%;
}     

.aboutbox1{
  max-width:20%;
    width:20%;
  min-width:20%;
  height:10vw;
  float:left;
}


#aboutbox-image1 {
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
    background-position: left top;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height: 100%;   
    border-radius: 1.8vw;
    border: hidden;
}

.aboutbox2{
  max-width:20%;
  min-width:20%;
  height:10vw;
  width:20%;
  float:left;
}

#aboutbox-image2 {

     background-image: url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
    background-position: left top;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height: 100%;   
    border-radius: 1.8vw;
    border: 25px solid #000000;

}
.aboutbox3{
    max-width:20%;
  min-width:20%;
  height:10vw;
  float:left;
width:20%;
}


#aboutbox-image3 {

     background-image: url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
    background-position: left top;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height: 100%;   
    border-radius: 1.8vw;
    border: hidden;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

How to float adjacent divs on a line:

1. for each adjacent div `float: left (or right if you want to read right-to-left)`
2. define a `width` for each (I recommend % width for responsive design)
3. To separate rows, wrap the adjacent divs inside another div and `clear: both` to reset the float.

```css
.aboutbox {
    width: 20%;
    float:left;
}
.aboutbox-image {
    height:10vw;
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 1.8vw;
}
.bordered {
    border: 25px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutbox">
    <div class="aboutbox-image">box1</div>
</div>
<div class="aboutbox">
    <div class="aboutbox-image bordered">box2</div>
</div>
<div class="aboutbox">
    <div class="aboutbox-image">box3</div>
</div>
```

That will clear the float so the next item starts on a new line.

Comment: **NOTE** I removed some redundancy in your CSS. Not sure what you were going for, so I guessed :)

Answer (score 0):

I think adding `vertical-align` property might help

```
vertical-align: top;
```